# Using a Property Value Inside of createCriteria

Tags: mysql, grails, jodatime

I have 2 domain classes, Item and Manufacturer.  The Manufacturer has a property on it to warn the user when the Item is about to expire (the date of which is stored as a Joda DateTime object).  The relevant fields are set up like so.

```
class Manufacturer {
    Integer expirationWarning

    static hasMany = [items: Item]
}
```

and

```
class Item {
    DateTime expirationDate

    static belongsTo = [manufacturer: Manufacturer]
}
```

I'm trying to create a list of Items where the expiration is some time between now and now plus expirationWarning days.  I have gotten the query working correctly in the MySQL terminal.

```
SELECT i.id FROM items as i 
   LEFT JOIN (manufacturer as m) ON (m.id = i.manufacturer_id) 
   WHERE i.expiration_date <= DATE_ADD(current_date, INTERVAL m.expiration_warning DAY);
```

Now I just need to execute the same query in Grails.  I know that the createCriteria will look something like this:

```
def itemsExpiringSoon = Item.createCriteria().list(max: listMax, offset: params.offset) {
    createAlias('manufacturer', 'm', CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
    le('expirationDate', new DateTime().plusDays('m.expirationWarning'))
    order('expirationDate', 'desc')
}
```

But I can't figure out what to put in place of 'm.expirationWarning' in order to use the value of that field in the DateTime.plusDays().  Any guidance on this would be incredibly helpful.

Comment: You are actually doing what you wanted to do. `new DateTime().plusDays('m.expirationWarning')` returns a Joda `DateTime` and you are comparing it with a `DateTime` as well. Which property are you thinking of?

Comment: @dmahapatro Whenever I run it like that, I get the following error `No signature of method: org.joda.time.DateTime.plusDays() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [m.expirationWarning]`

I need to get the value of `m.expirationWarning` to insert into the `plusDays()` method.

Comment: Don't put single quotes around `m.expirationWarning` in your query : `le('expirationDate', new DateTime().plusDays(m.expirationWarning))`. My guess is that they stop interpolation.

Comment: @Kelly That one returns with `No such property: m for class: grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder`  Keep in mind that `m` is a seperate table that I need to pull the value `expirationWarning` from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two and a half years later, I finally figured out a solution to this problem.

I created what is, in effect, a transient property that I applied GORM formulas to, that represents the current date plus the manufacturer specified expiration warning.

```
class Item {
    Date expirationDate
    Date pendingExpiration

    static belongsTo = [manufacturer: Manufacturer]
    static mapping = {
         pendingExpiration formula: "(SELECT ADDDATE(current_date, mfr.expiration_warning) FROM manufacurer mfr WHERE mfr.id = manufacturer_id LIMIT 1)"
    }
}
```

Now I can query against this property, and it will update dynamically as Manufacturer.expirationWarning does.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mix your query in this way, but the criteria have an option to add sql directly, then you can use your `date_add()`.

```
def itemsExpiringSoon = Item.createCriteria().list(max: listMax, offset: params.offset) {
    createAlias('manufacturer', 'm', CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
    sqlRestriction('m.expiration_warning <= DATE_ADD(current_date, INTERVAL m.expiration_warning DAY)')
    order('expirationDate', 'desc')
}
```

Note that in `sqlRestriction()` you write something that will be added in the final `SQL`, so we use the name of the database column, and not the attribute of the domain class.